Java - Getting from Clipboard is broken after setting to Clipboard
I'm using the Robot class in Java to copy Strings from other programs. This works correctly, provided I don't set the contents of the clipboard programmatically before attempting to copy. Setting the contents of the clipboard seems to prevent Java from seeing changes to the clipboard made by other programs.
The copied content is actually in the clipboard. This can be tested by pasting into notepad or another text window.  However, getting the contents of the clipboard in Java returns the previously set value, not the copied value.
try {
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection("empty"), null);

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

            robot.delay(50);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

            String currentContents = clipboard.getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
            System.out.println(currentContents);
        } catch (AWTException | UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

The java version is 17.0.6

I wonder if it's because the 50ms delay is too short. After trying your code myself and adding an additional 200ms delay before and after pressing Ctrl+C, the clipboard content is properly read for me.

Did you test the clipboard by trying to paste into a text window after running the program?
When I run this, the Java clipboard is not set, but the Windows clipboard does contain the Ctrl+A - Ctrl+C data.
